# ¿Cómo funciona el when()?

Tags: jquery

He mirado en su [API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) y en [este ejemplo](https://codepen.io/MidnightLightning/pen/NPNWQX?editors=1010) pero no logro comprender su uso bien.

```js
var def1 = $.Deferred();
var def2 = $.Deferred();
var def3 = $.Deferred();

var p1 = def1.promise();
var p2 = def2.promise();
var p3 = def3.promise();


$.when(p1, p2, p3).done(function(rs1, rs2, rs3) {
  LOG('When complete: '+rs1+', '+rs2+', '+rs3); // Results are in the order of the promises, regardless of the order they resolved in
});

def1.resolve('foo');
def3.resolve('bar');

setTimeout(function() {
  def2.resolve('AJAX!'); // No output is sent until this one returns
}, 2000);


function LOG(msg) {
  $('#log').append('<p>'+msg+'</p>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details">
  An example of using <tt>when()</tt> to wait for all promises
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

**¿Alguien sabe como funciona?**

Comment: Este link te puede servir con tus dudas: http://www.formandome.es/javascript/promises-y-deferreds-en-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como suele ser habitual en `jQuery`, el comportamiento de la función `when` varía según los parámetros usados, pero en el caso que planteas es igual al de [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all):

```js
let p1= new Promise(function (resolver) {
  setTimeout(()=> resolver('medio segundo'), 500);
});
let p2= new Promise(function (resolver) {
  setTimeout(()=> resolver('1 segundo'), 1000);
});
let p3= new Promise(function (resolver) {
  setTimeout(()=> resolver('2 segundos'), 2000);
});

$.when(p1,p2,p3).then( (r1,r2,r3) => {
  console.log('Todo resuelto:',r1,r2,r3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Es decir, agrupa promesas y crea una nueva promesa que se resolverá cuando **todas** las promesas agrupadas se hayan resuelto.

Es útil, por ejemplo, cuando necesitas hacer varias llamadas `AJAX` y necesitas que todas se completen antes de realizar una acción, pero no quieres encadenarlas porque se pueden ejecutar en paralelo. De este modo ganas tiempo y el código queda más limpio:

```
let peticion1 = $.ajax(....);
let peticion2 = $.ajax(...);

$.when(peticion1,peticion2).then(function (respuesta1,respuesta2) { ... });
```

Su equivalente con Javascript *vanilla* sería (nótese los corchetes, los parámetros se agrupan en un `array`):

```
let peticion1=fetch(...);
let peticion2=fetch(...);

Promise.all([peticion1, peticion2]). then(function ([res1,res2]) => {...});
```